# Incompleteness theorem and $\mathbb{L}$.

Tags: logic, set-theory, incompleteness

Let $\alpha > \omega$ and $u = \{\ulcorner \sigma \urcorner : \sigma \in \mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{L}_\alpha, \in)\} \subseteq \omega$, where by $\mathbb{L}_\alpha$ we denote as usual the constructible sets up to level $\alpha$.

My question is "Can we have $u \in \mathbb{L}_\alpha$?".

Suppose we can. Let $\phi(x) := x \in u$. Then for every sentence $\sigma$ we have that $$\mathbb{L}_\alpha \models \phi(\ulcorner \sigma \urcorner) \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{L}_\alpha \models \sigma,$$
i.e. truth is definable in $(\mathbb{L}_\alpha, \in)$, which contradicts the incompleteness theorem.

So $\mathscr{P}(\omega) \nsubseteq \mathbb{L}_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \mathrm{ON}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the same can apply with the universe of set theory:

For example let $u=\{\ulcorner\sigma\urcorner : \sigma\in\mathrm{Th}(V_\alpha,\in)\}\subseteq\omega$. Then for $\alpha>\omega+1$ we have that $u\in V_\alpha$. Then the formula $x\in u$ yeilds $$V_\alpha\models\ulcorner\sigma\urcorner\in u\iff V_\alpha\models\sigma$$ i.e. there is nothing special about the constructible universe.

The problem with the argument is that the formula $x\in u$ is *not* definable from the language of the model (i.e. $\{\in\}$), but from the language with an extra constant term $u$. The model may not be able (in fact by Tarski's theorem it is not able) to define -using its language- the set $u$, creating no conflict with Tarski's theorem.

The subsets of $\omega$ that you describe are always in $\mathbb{L}$ since they are definable with parameters from $\mathbb{L}_{\alpha+2}$ for example. They are simply not definable in $\mathbb{L}_\alpha$.

As an interesting aside (that Jech notes), if $0^\sharp$ exists then the theory of $\mathbb{L}$ is the same as that of $\mathbb{L}_{\aleph_1}$, so the theory of $\mathbb{L}$ is an element of $\mathbb{L}$. This means that in that case the real $\aleph_1$ is not definable in $\mathbb{L}$, making it quite large.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since you seem to grasp these things better than me, can you answer two more questions? Can you name any subsets of $\omega$ that are missing from $\mathbb{L}_\alpha$? Also, how could someone show that a certain $u \subseteq \omega$ is not in $\mathbb{L}$?

Comment: @fnimic: In general we cannot show that $V\neq\mathbb{L}$, that is, if $ZFC$ is consistent so is $ZFC+V=\mathbb{L}$. That  $V\neq\mathbb{L}$ follows from large cardinal hypotheses. $0^\sharp$ contradicts $V=\mathbb{L}$. What I say in the last paragraph of my answer also implies that $V\neq\mathbb{L}$, since otherwise $\aleph_1$ would be definable as the least non-countable ordinal. In $\mathbb{L}$ under $0^\sharp$, $\aleph_1$ is a large cardinal, e.g. it is Mahlo and in fact not the least Mahlo in $\mathbb{L}$.

Comment: @fnimic: I should point out that the consistency of $V=\mathbb{L}$ relative to ZFC is very easy to see, since $\mathbb{L}$ is an absolute model of ZFC, so $\mathbb{L}^\mathbb{L}=\mathbb{L}$ (and therefore $\mathbb{L}\models ZFC+V=\mathbb{L}$).

Comment: I understand. I just have a problem figuring out some examples of subsets of $\omega$ that are in $\mathbb{L}_{\omega+n+1} - \mathbb{L}_{\omega+n}$. I thought that maybe such sets are sets of Goedel numbers of theories, but as you showed me this is wrong. Even in the presence of $O^\#$, does $\omega^{\mathbb{L}}$ keep getting bigger (until we reach $\mathbb{L}_{\aleph_1}$)? What I mean is, why would we get a new real for example at some point $\mathbb{L}_\alpha$ for $\alpha$ very large?

Comment: @fnimic That is a very interesting question. You keep getting reals because if $\alpha$ is countable in $L$, then $L_\alpha$ is countable in $L$. Since there are more than $\omega$ many reals, there most be more reals in $L$ than those in $L_\alpha$. On the other hand, Gödel's condensation lemma (essentially a consequence of Lowenheim-Skolem) gives that every real appears in some $L_\alpha$, with $\alpha$ countable. So there most be cofinally many countable $\alpha$ where $L_{\alpha+1}\setminus L_\alpha$ has a real. (Cont.)

Comment: @fnimic When first studied these stages, people talked of *gaps*. You are essentially right that in many cases the new reals are just describing the theory of the previous stage (this eventually was developed by Jensen into the notion of master codes in fine structure). An excellent introductory paper on these matters (not requiring any fine structure, and quite accessible) is W. Marek, M. Srebrny. *Gaps in the constructible universe*, Ann. Math. Logic 6 (1973/74), 359-394.

Comment: @Caicedo Thank you very much.

Comment: @fnimic: It should be stressed that when Anders mentions countable ordinals he means ordinals that $\mathbb{L}$ sees as countable (Anders states this, but since this creates confusion many times I think it should be highlighted). For example if $0^\sharp$ exists, then there are only countable many reals in $\mathbb{L}$. In that case the reals stop appearing at level $\aleph_1^\mathbb{L}$ which is a countable ordinal (in the "actual" universe).